# How to create digital sounds?

Tags: recording

I'm a software developer, totally amateur at creating sounds.

But for my app I need to create new sounds that are unique.

How is it possible to create digital sounds, as is often the case in notification software?

Is an app like Garage Band necessary or should I use instruments?

For example, the sound in this video, how could it have been created?

Comment: One thing you might research is Max MSP.

Comment: Are you looking for bleeps and blorps? Single click-type bings are easy, but if you want more complicated jingly bleep-blorps, it's more difficult. You could support the field by paying someone to create a set. It would be pretty cheap.

Comment: I really think it would be best to hire a professional for this.
But the region I am in and the country I am in, it is somewhat more complicated to find this type of professional.

Comment: All you need is an internet connection. I did some work on fiver, but the effort wasn't worth the cash. There are free sample libraries out there too. The ads while browsing pay for them.

Comment: The example was probably created using music creation software and a software synthesizer. It is a brief moment of music. I agree that looking on the internet for someone to make sounds for you is a good strategy. Facebook groups, fiver, and social media in general are good places to find people.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get started with designing sounds if you don't want to spend much time learning how to do it yourself, is buying/downloading sample packs or hiring someone.

Freesound.com for example has plenty of sounds. Search by word or tags:
https://freesound.org/browse/tags/Interface/

If you want to get more musical, check out Elektron's packs: https://www.elektron.se/no/all-products/sound-packs

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to create notification sounds. Really all you need is some kind of [Synthesizer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MNds9fJvu4) and a [Chord](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USoXc3p3ZW0) to play.

You can easily get some good jingles by playing the individual notes of a chord one after the other. or using an arpeggiator to automatically get some interesting melodies and rhythms.